# database locking problems with django

Tags: mysql, django, multithreading, locking

I have a webpage which interacts with several external APIs and in order to speed things up (the speed increase is almost linear because the majority of the time is spent waiting for http responses, etc), the code is threaded so that it pulls the content from several APIs at once.

The problem is, I am running into database locking presumably due to the fact that data from the apis is being written to the database by more than one thread simultaneously.

**What can I do to eliminate this problem?**

PS - please do not suggest making the api calls sequentially... The same problems will occur when multiple users are importing data at the same time, except that without the threading, it'll be slower for everyone. And we're talking about the difference between 15 seconds and several minutes.

Comment: What database are you using? What wrapper?

Comment: well I have confirmed the issue on sqlite3 on my development machine, and I highly suspect the same issue on mysql on the development server since I am seeing the same behavior (database not getting updated)

Comment: I confirmed it by running the test server and seeing the error message that said 'OperationalError: database is locked'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely don't try this with SQLite: its major weakness is concurrency.

If MySQL shows the same problem, then you should collect all the data together and then write it from a single thread.

Comment: good idea... doing all the writes after the data has been gathered is a little ugly but definitely will solve the problem :)